# OpenGL ES 3.0 with CMake Error

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, opengl-es-3.0

In order to open the examples provided from the textbook, I downloaded the examples from the book's website at opengl-book.com.

The instructions say:
Point CMake to the folder and VS 2013 is suppose to take it from there.
However, I get and error message on CMake. 
Error says:
'Error in configuration process, files may be invalid'.

CMake Error: The source directory "E:/OpenGL ES/opengles3-book" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

What step am I missing here?

Comment: Please include your research efforts and give specific code examples that demonstrate the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: According to the OpenGL ES 3.0 Programming Guide, 2nd Ed. textbook, Chapter 16, it simply says to point Cmake to the folder and its suppose to build the examples provided. This are the errors I get:

Comment: According to the OpenGL ES 3.0 Programming Guide, 2nd Ed. textbook, Chapter 16, it simply says to point Cmake to the folder and its suppose to build the examples provided. These are the errors: Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo                                      C:/Program Files/ES3_Book    egl library not found,  opengles3_library not found. Looks like a wrong installation in directory folders.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message is pretty clear. You are missing a CMakeLists.txt in the said folder. I don't know what instructions you are following, but I suggest you take a look at how CMake works, e.g. http://mirkokiefer.com/blog/2013/03/cmake-by-example/.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for getting back to me. According to the textbook instructions the instructions were 'pretty simple', but it looks like the authors of the book didn't specify some knowledge of Cmake. I will start to get somewhat familiar with it. Thanks for this lead.